# Ask for a user input to start fibonacci sequence using recursion

Tags: java, string

How can I get the **user input and read it into other method**
I tried this code but it keeps saying that the variable is not defined

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num =15;
    int n3 = 0;
    System.out.print(n1+"+"+n2);
    displayFib(num-2);
    int userInput = input (n1,n2);
}
public static int input (int n1, int n2){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter num: ");
    n1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter num: ");
    n2 = sc.nextInt();
    return n1,n2;
   }
public static void displayFib(int num){
    if(num>0){
   n3 = n1+n2;
   n1 = n2;
   n2=n3;
        System.out.print(""+'+'+n3);
        displayFib(num-1);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your code has compilation issues and your question is not clear. Can you please add more details ? Also why are returning two values from input method `return n1,n2;` when your return type is single integer. Also there are some other issues of initialization in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question: For using variables across multiple functions, you have to declare them globally.
Still I think there are few errors in the code. Here's the code for reference

```
class fibonacci 
{ 
    static int fib(int n) 
    { 
    if (n <= 1) 
       return n; 
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); 
    } 
       
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    { 
    int n = 9; 
    System.out.println(fib(n)); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the variables `static` so that they can be accessed in all your methods.

```
private static int n1, n2, n3;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input();
    int num = 15;
    displayFib(num-2);
}
public static void input (){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter num: ");
    n1 = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter num: ");
    n2 = sc.nextInt();
}
```